# Use value returned by query A in query B in a grafana panel

Tags: grafana

I would like to transform a dashboard variable (using for example Postgres), and then use the returned value in a second query (against Prometheus).

I can't use chained variables, because I'm inside a repeated row.

Here's what I would want to do:

Query A (I'm using Postgres, but really could be anything, I just want to transform the variable using substring or maybe regex replace)

```
SELECT substr('$my_row_variable',5)
```

Query B (PromQL - obviously the `$A` doesn't work, but you get my point)

```
sum(kube_pod_status_ready{pod=~"$A.*"})
```

Things I've tried:

- I have explored using the Grafana/Panel datasource but that doesn't seem to do the trick (gives me the entire panel, and can't really be reused)
- Grafana's built in functions for variable formatting (which could remove the need for the first query entirely) don't seem to allow regex transformation, only basic stuff like csv format, escaping etc.
- I have no control over the row variable before hand (it is supplied from a different source, and it needs to be left as-is for other panels to work)

Comment: If first 5 symbols of your variable are unique, you could create variable with values containing first 5 symbols and allow select needed of them. When you need full variable: use regex selector like `label =~ "${my_row_variable}.*"`

Comment: I have no control over the row variable. And it needs to be exactly as is for other panels to work (updated my question to show this)

Comment: Oh, I've totally forgot about requirement for join field to be unique. So we can use it as "filter". Well in that case I don't believe that task (as it is) is possible to accomplish: grafana variables are not really meant for elaborate manipulation.

Comment: If you can abandon repeated dasboards if favor of single dashboard, I believe I could suggest some combination of chained variables, `sum by` and `label_replace`, though.